# git mv file and create symbolic link at old location (shell command needed)

Tags: git, bash, shell, symlink

I want to move files from one location to another in a git repository. However, I would like that programs can still access the files at the old location, thus I want to create a symlink at the old location.

Now I don't want to manually enter two commands in the shell, like "git mv oldfile newfile; ln -s newfile oldfile". I would need to enter the files twice, that could lead to more typos.

I am using the bash shell in linux. Can I write my own command `git-mv-keep` that executes the git-mv and ln commands? I am a newbie in bash.

Comment: Do you want the symlinks tracked in the git repository or just on your local disk? If just on your local disk then what's the point of this?

Comment: I want it in the repository for now, then at some later point when all works fine and is tested, I want to remove the symlinks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use history shortcuts

```
git mv oldfile newfile
ln -s !$ !:2
```

or a short function:

```
git-mv-link() { git mv "$1" "$2" && ln -s "$2" "$1"; }
```

Comment: That short function can then be added as an alias for `git`, with a proper invocation of `git config ...` - or just edit `~/.gitconfig` manually...

Comment: As written, no. With some minor tweaking you could make that a git alias and then use `git mv-link old new`, yes. `mv-link = "!bash -c 'git mv "$1" "$2" && ln -s "$2" "$1" && git add "$1"' -"` or something like that I think.

Comment: or `mv-link = '! f() { git mv "$1" "$2" && ln -s "$2" "$1"; } f'`, which is somewhat simpler... Also, it doesn't spawn two sub-shells like `! bash -c ...` does...